# Compiler - Log error in SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

[image]

When I am trying to execute,

```
 CREATE TYPE doctor_ty AS OBJECT(
  sysID char(6),
  regNo char(10),
  name varchar2(50),
  specialization varchar2(25)
);
/
```

it will generate error as in above picture. Eventhough type get compiled why I am getting such error. Each time when I'm trying to execute a query related to type in sqldeveloper it will generate the same log file error

Comment: as a side note why are you using char for your sysID instead of a GUID, Varchar2 or number?

Comment: What did the teacher suggest as the answer to your question? That's what they are paid for, to answer student questions.

Comment: Because sysID should contains char values

Comment: The question was why char values (which are blank-padded) instead of varchar2?

Comment: Anyway, PLS-00330 won't be raised on this CREATE TYPE command (it works fine on my system) but on some other code, perhaps later in your script.